# generic XSLT for a dynamic XML ,whose structure is same,for sum function

Tags: xslt-1.0

suppose that the structure of my xml file is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<main>
    <_All>
        <_999999>
            <Employee_Amount>10.0</Employee_Amount>
            <Cash_Count>10.0</Cash_Count>
            <Dine_in_Amount>10.0</Dine_in_Amount>
            <Promos_Actual>10.0</Promos_Actual>
            <Combo_Savings_Amount>10.0</Combo_Savings_Amount>
            <total_sales>10.0</total_sales>
            </_999999>
        <_test>
            <Employee_Amount>20.0</Employee_Amount>
            <Cash_Count>20.0</Cash_Count>
            <Dine_in_Amount>20.0</Dine_in_Amount>
            <Promos_Actual>20.0</Promos_Actual>
            <Combo_Savings_Amount>20.0</Combo_Savings_Amount>
            <total_sales>20.0</total_sales>
            </_test>
    </_All>
</main>
```

I have to sum all the nodes (for example - Cash_Count of both the nodes,total_sales of both the nodes), the node name can be change so I cannot use its name to navigate. I have tried for-each but i stuck with the xpath expressions. since I am new to xslt 1.0, Please help me for the same.

I have tried with the below xslt with the help of what proskor suggested me in the answers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/*" mode="wrap"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name(child::*)"/></td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/*[current()]">
                          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                         <td> <xsl:value-of select="sum(/*/*/*/*[$pos])" /></td>
                  </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/*" mode="values"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*/*" mode="wrap">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <th>Region</th>
    <th>Store</th>
    <xsl:for-each select="./*">
    <th><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></th>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*" mode="values">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <tr>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it worked fine but produses output with extra ***td*** with values 0 to it. since there are 6 nodes hence there are 6 extra ***td*** with the value 0 to it. 
after sum this ***tr*** looks like this..

```
<tr>
<td>30</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
```

Please anyone help to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Please clarify which nodes are dynamic.

Comment: the above shown xml is created from database, so the structure is same but all the nodes and there values will be different.

Comment: If the node names are dynamic, how do you know which nodes you want to sum?

Comment: @ChrisW i need to add all the nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the select-attribute of the xsl:for-each element on line 14 to `"/*[1]/*[1]/*[1]/*"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/*" mode="wrap"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name(child::*)"/></td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <xsl:for-each select="/*[1]/*[1]/*[1]/*">
                          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                         <td> <xsl:value-of select="sum(/*/*/*/*[$pos])" /></td>
                  </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/*" mode="values"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*/*" mode="wrap">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <th>Region</th>
    <th>Store</th>
    <xsl:for-each select="./*">
    <th><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></th>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*" mode="values">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <tr>
            <td>&#160;</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: its cool, but i can't use main/_All. it could be change. I mean that i need a generic xsl for the same structured xml.

Comment: Then use *[1]/*[1] instead.

Comment: it doesn't sum all the relative nodes

Comment: What do you mean by "relative nodes"?

Comment: Thanks for your help. it works for me as i have updated my question that the output comes with some extra td with the value 0 to it. How can I remove them. please suggest. Thanks once again...